# How to make a composable time limited?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable in Jetpack Compose, lets say its a Button. I would like to make it time limited, so that after this time elapses, the Composable, here the button disappears.

Is there any easy way to realize this with Composables?

Or is this a much more complex implenentation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An easy way to change the state of the view after some delay is to use `LaunchedEffect` - it is executed in the coroutine scope, so you can use the `delay` function with the desired interval and change the state value when it finishes.

```kotlin
var isButtonVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
if (isButtonVisible) {
    Button(onClick = {}) {
        Text("Button")
    }
}
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(5.seconds)
    isButtonVisible = false
}
```

A more complex example, which will also show the reverse counter:

```kotlin
var isButtonVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
var secondsToDisappear by remember { mutableStateOf(5) }
if (isButtonVisible) {
    Button(onClick = {}) {
        Text("Button will disappear in $secondsToDisappear seconds")
    }
}
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    while (secondsToDisappear > 0) {
        delay(1.seconds)
        secondsToDisappear -= 1
    }
    isButtonVisible = false
}
```